# How to insert into a record in object from one developer id throught another?

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, salesforce2salesforce

I have two salesforce account.
username 1: `XYZ`
username 2: `ABC`

I have credentials for both accounts.

What I want to do is that insert a record in `X` object lies in `XYZ` account through `ABC` account.
Is there a way that I can have a class in `ABC` such that whenever I call the constructor of this class in `ABC` there should insert a row in `X` object which lies in `XYZ` account.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least four ways to accomplish this, depending specific behaviors desired and how "real-time" you need it. Here are some basic ideas, sorted by amount of effort and overall average lag you would experience using the service, from fastest and easiest, to slowest and most complex. Keep in mind that while the solutions here are represented in "average" time, system performance depends on overall load, which will be slower in the day and faster at night (on average).

First, there is [Salesforce-to-Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce), a zero-code solution that lets you synchronize records between two organizations effortlessly. You can read the documentation on how this feature works. This connection is effectively real-time, with very little lag in updates between the organizations. You can easily configure which records you'd like to keep in sync.

Secondly, you could use [Email Services](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_inbound_what_is.htm). The idea would be to set up a second user in the organization with the email address used for the Email Services class on the far side. Then, you can use workflow rules or triggers to send emails to the other organization. This is minimal amounts of coding, but it wouldn't be terribly difficult to maintain. There will be a time delay equal to the amount of time it takes for salesforce to send and receive the email and process the record, probably on average just a few seconds. There's no easy way of confirmation that the other org received the data, however, so that might be a significant penalty, and there's a per-day limit that you may reach if you use the system heavily.

Third, you can use the [REST](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/) or [SOAP](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/) APIs to communicate between organizations. Since you already have the user name and password, you could build a solution to send the data asynchronously. I'd set up some custom object to track records that need to be sent over, then periodically process those records with a scheduled job. This would have a minimal delay involved, probably up to a few minutes depending on the design. This design also requires you to maintain either a refresh token or the password so that the integration doesn't fail. As such, it's relatively fragile. There's also a risk of using precious API calls (these regenerate daily) if something goes wrong, and those limits are lower than Email Services or Salesforce to Salesforce, on a per-license basis.

Finally, you could also set up a replication service offline somewhere that logs into both orgs, periodically polls for changes with the replication API (a subset of the SOAP API's features), then sends any changes across to the other org. This is usually considered a little more prohibitive, as now you're involving your own hardware just to keep the integration going, and requires more housekeeping than the other solutions. It is, however, reliable, and you can still use features like workflow rules to send outbound notifications to the system to reduce latency between synchronization.